# Python Requests: Using lists when specifying parameters

Tags: python, python-requests

Trying to fetch currency quotes from Oanda's API. Here is the code I have:

```
s = requests.Session()
url = "https://stream-fxpractice.oanda.com/v1/prices"
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token}
params = {'instruments': pairs_oanda, 'accountId': account_id}
resp = s.get(url, headers=headers, params=params, stream=True)
```

The access_token and account_id are authentication for the API. When I supply one currency pair, for instance "EUR_USD", to pairs_oanda it works fine, resulting in the following url:

```
https://streamfxpractice.oanda.com/v1/prices?instruments=GBP_USD&accountId=*******
```

However, when I supply a list of currency pairs, for instance

```
["EUR_USD", "GBP_USD"]
```

to pairs_oanda, I get this URL:

```
https://stream-fxpractice.oanda.com/v1/prices?instruments=EUR_USD&instruments=GBP_USD&accountId=*******
```

However, what I need the url to look like to properly access the API is this:

```
https://stream-fxpractice.oanda.com/v1/prices?instruments=EUR_USD%2CGBP_USD&accountId=*******
```

Is there anyway to get Requests to parse the list differently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The API wants you to use a *comma* to separate the currency pairs. You'll have to do so yourself; use `str.join()` here:

```
pairs_oanda = ["EUR_USD", "GBP_USD"]
params = {'instruments': ','.join(pairs_oanda), 'accountId': account_id}
```

The `%2C` character sequence is a `,` encoded to URL encoding:

```
>>> from urlparse import unquote
>>> unquote('%2C')
','
```

and `requests` takes care of quoting for you provided you give it the unquoted parameter values:

```
>>> from requests import Request
>>> url = "https://stream-fxpractice.oanda.com/v1/prices"
>>> pairs_oanda = ["EUR_USD", "GBP_USD"]
>>> params = {'instruments': ','.join(pairs_oanda), 'accountId': 'foobarbaz'}
>>> r = Request('GET', url, params=params)
>>> r.prepare().url
'https://stream-fxpractice.oanda.com/v1/prices?instruments=EUR_USD%2CGBP_USD&accountId=foobarbaz'
```

Comment: Ah, there we go. Bit new to the website, as you can probably tell. Thanks for the help